# Как сделать разделение по абзацам в джанго

Tags: python, django

Здарствуйте!Недавно заметил вот-такой дефект, у меня есть свой сайт,создавал сам - http://pasha-blog.herokuapp.com , сайт простой, там есть одна проблема - при создание поста [image]

текст разделен на абзацы, а на самом сайте, если зайдете - тест разделен в плотную. Как сделать чтобы текст отображался так же как и у меня на картинке.Синьте пожалуйста ссылку как это сделать или просто расскажите!

views.py -
 `class ObjectDetailMixin:
    model = None
    template = None
    def get(self, request, slug):
        obj = get_object_or_404(self.model, slug__iexact=slug)
        return render(request, self.template, context={self.model.__name__.lower(): obj, 'admin_object': obj, 'detail': True})`
точнее миксин, вот вьюхи - 
    `class PostDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
        model = Post
        template = 'blog/post_detail.html'`

вот мой шаблон  -

```
`

{% extends 'blog/base_blog.html' %}{% block title %}
    {{ post.title }} - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
    <h1 class="mt-5">
        {{ post.title }}
    </h1>
    <span>
        {{post.body}}
    </span>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1 class="mt-5">
        {{ post.title }}
    </h1>
    <span>
        {{post.body}}
    </span>
{% endblock %}
```

`

Comment: А как именно Вы создаёте пост? И откуда взят скриншот? Пожалуйста, приведите код, который отвечает за этот функционал.

Comment: {% extends 'blog/base_blog.html' %}


{% block title %}
 {{ post.title }} - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
 <h1 class="mt-5">
  {{ post.title }}
 </h1>
 <span>
  {{post.body}}
 </span>
{% endblock %}

Comment: nomnoms12 - 
{% extends 'blog/base_blog.html' %} {% block title %} {{ post.title }} - {{ block.super }} {% endblock %} {% block content %} <h1 class="mt-5"> {{ post.title }} </h1> <p> {{post.body}} </p> {% endblock %}

Comment: Лучше редактируйте ответ, комментарии не предназначены для этого + в ответе есть форматирование кода на значке `{}`. И да, данный код не отвечает напрямую за текст, он только использует заготовленный текст `{{post.body}}` откуда-то еще.

Comment: Выше Вы привели код шаблона, но это не даёт информации о том, какие данные передаются и как они обрабатываются. Приведите, пожалуйста, Ваши представления (`views.py`), отвечающие за это. Добавить код в вопрос Вы можете, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: { class ObjectDetailMixin:
 model = None
 template = None
 def get(self, request, slug):
  obj = get_object_or_404(self.model, slug__iexact=slug)
  return render(request, self.template, context={self.model.__name__.lower(): obj, 'admin_object': obj, 'detail': True}) }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте так {{post.body|linebreaks}}

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в шаблоне.
Обычно на страницу выводится текст, не взирая на `\n`

```
{% block content %}
    <h1 class="mt-5">
        {{ post.title }}
    </h1>
    <p style="white-space:pre-line">
        {{post.body}}
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```